# Syntax error in sql statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an sql statement that looks like this:

```
delete from survey_results sr
left outer join people p on p.id = sr.person_id
left outer join survey_result_sets srs on srs.id = sr.survey_result_set_id
left outer join survey_schemas ss on ss.id = sr.survey_schema_id
where (sr.person_id is not null and p.id is null)
OR (srs.id is null)
OR (ss.id is null);
```

but it gaves an syntax error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "left"
LINE 2: left outer join people p on p.id = sr.person_id
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

You **can't use JOIN in DELETE statement** in **PostgreSQL**. Instead use USING and put the second table there. Something like this should work

```
   delete from survey_results sr
using people p on p.id = sr.person_id
using  survey_result_sets srs on srs.id = sr.survey_result_set_id
using  survey_schemas ss on ss.id = sr.survey_schema_id
where (sr.person_id is not null and p.id is null)
OR (srs.id is null)
OR (ss.id is null);
```

You can refer this [PostgreSQL-delete](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-delete.html)

Comment: When I paste your code to my database console it returns me:
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "sr"
LINE 1: delete sr

Comment: Hi @MateuszUrbański If you are using PostgreSQL then you cant use joins in the delete

Comment: Your code still gaves syntax error:
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "on"
LINE 2: using people p on p.id = sr.person_id

But when googling there are a lot of topics people using delete with joins in postgress.

Comment: You are right with this joins but I still can't make this query to work. Why this syntax error is causing?

Comment: `USING` can only be used once in a `DELETE` statement it's pretty much the same as the `FROM` clause in a `SELECT` statement

Answer (score 1):

How about :

```
begin;
create temp table table_survey_result_pk on commit drop as select survey_result_pk from survey_results sr
left outer join people p on p.id = sr.person_id
left outer join survey_result_sets srs on srs.id = sr.survey_result_set_id
left outer join survey_schemas ss on ss.id = sr.survey_schema_id
where (sr.person_id is not null and p.id is null)
OR (srs.id is null)
OR (ss.id is null);
delete from survey_results t using table_survey_result_pk d on t.survey_result_pk = d.survey_result_pk;
commit;
```